Generalized Laplacian
I was wondering if any of you had ever encountered operators on
$L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ of the form
$$
\nabla \cdot (A(x)\nabla)
$$
where $A(x)$ is some symmetric matrix field (viewed as $L^2(\mathbb{R}^{2^2}$)), and if so where can I find some literature about it?
More precisely, I'd like to know more about the solution to the associated Dirichlet problem on the exterior of the unit disk
$$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
\nabla \cdot (A \nabla u) &=& 0 & \text{in $\Omega$}\\ 
u &=& f & \text{on $\partial \Omega$}
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
Thanks a lot!
N.B. 1: Indeed, such operators are often encountered in differential geometry, where a Laplace operator on a Riemannian manifold with metric $g$ is given by
$$ \Delta f = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det g}} \nabla\cdot(g^{-1}\sqrt{\det g}\nabla f)$$ However, in 2D $g^{-1}\sqrt{\det g}$ has unit determinant, which is not necessarily the case with $A$.
N.B. 2: When $A$ is the identity matrix, the solution to the above Dirichlet problem can be obtained in terms of the Poisson kernel for the disk. I seek a generalization of that procedure for the case of arbitrary $A$.

YouTube might want to Look ATM the book by Berligne, Geißler anf Vergne "Heat Kernels and Dirac operators" where such Operators are considered.

Thanks a lot. I'll take a look at it.

I am probably not smart enough to find much of relevance to my problem in Berline et al. I could find this paper, though Clements - A fundamental solution for linear second-order elliptic systems with variable coefficients where such operators are addressed, but only for the particular case that $A$ is a constant symetric matrix times a harmonic scalar function. I am wondering does anyone know a paper for more general cases?
